# clocktable tag filter not working?

Tags: org-mode

I try to make a clocktable report that filters by tags like so:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tags ("REP") :tstart "<-6d>" :tend "<now>"
...
#+END:
```

But I get an error:
Wrong argument type: stringp, ("REP").

If I remove `:tags ("REP")` then it works. But I'd like to filter by tag.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**[edit]** 
On the side similar 'clocktable-by-tags' post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353591/timetable-grouped-by-tag

This is similar to what I want, but not quite it. I'd like the classical clocktable report but only display entries that match certain tags. (REP meaining things that go on my weekly REPort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2 years later, but you can ditch the parens around the tag name:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tags "REP" :tstart "<-6d>" :tend "<now>"
...
#+END:
```

to include headlines with tag REP and

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tags "-REP" :tstart "<-6d>" :tend "<now>"
...
#+END:
```

to exclude headlines with tag REP.

Comment: I have no idea if the above works, but thanks for getting back to me. (I've sort of moved to Zim for notes these days).

Comment: For others coming to this, the current way to filter by tags is to use `:match "<tagname>"`. Having `:tags` just shows a tag column in the clock table.

Comment: what if you wanted to check multiple columns?